# hoverPause on thumbnails

Tags: jquery, pagination, slideshow, thumbnails

I'm using the slidesjs jquery slideshow found here http://slidesjs.com, and I need to be able to use the ul.pagination instead of the slide container as the pause. So that it will pause the slideshow when hovering over the thumbnails instead of the slides.

here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BygiprsMTsKTZGdSeGxzbjBUdWlwejh2RzZQN01qQQ) to the standard js file I'm using for this slideshow.

**If you have no insight on the issue at hand please do not correct the grammatical errors. I came for help with coding not grammer.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain what is and isn't working.

Comment: i tried this but it just breaks on hover and all images disappear and it generates more li for pagination.           $(".caption").hover(
  function () {
 $('#slides').slides('pause');
    //$(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  }
);